# How to simplify cos(pi)?

Tags: maxima

I'am new to Maxima and would like to use it for Denavit-Hartenberg matrices (consists of a lot of cos and sin terms). The problem is, that maxima does not simplify the following expression:

```
ex: x*cos(pi);
```

I expect, that Maxima simplifies `ex` to `-x`. How can this been done? (`ratsimp(ex)` and `trigsimp(ex)` have no effects)

Comment: The value of cos(pi) is -1

Comment: @RobertHarvey, he knows ("I expect that Maxima simplifies `ex` to `-x`").

Comment: The Maxima documentation shows a lot of expression manipulation functions [here](http://eagle.cs.kent.edu/MAXIMA/maxima_15.html). Trigsimp does painfully little to simplify that kind of expression. (Also, they use `%pi` instead of `pi`.)

Comment: Thank you! wxMaxima displays `pi` as the greek letter, so I supposed that this is the right constant. With `%pi` Maxima simplifies it correct without additional work :)

Comment: @zneak, can you post your comment as an answer please?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In Maxima's dialect, the correct name of the constant is `%pi`. With it, it should simplify correctly.

Answer (score 3):

As others have said, `%pi` is the correct name of the constant in Maxima.  `pi` is simply rendered as π in GUIs like wxMaxima because all Greek letters are (you can have a variable named "π", which has nothing to do with the value of the constant π=3.14159...).

By the way, other predefined constants are written with the `%` character as well, such as for example

```
%e (=exp(1))
%i (=sqrt(-1))
%phi (the golden section)
```

The manual's [index](http://maxima.sourceforge.net/docs/manual/en/maxima_82.html#SEC380_3) lists all `%` candidates.

Note that [other useful constants](http://maxima.sourceforge.net/docs/manual/en/maxima_5.html#SEC20) that can not be expressed by digits, such as `inf` or `false` do not have the percent character.